# Android logcat doesn't seem to capture the logs when I test my database

Tags: android, database, logcat

I created a database and I was testing the functions by adding a few values and reading it in the log. This is in my main class:

```
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting.. ");
    db.addProduct(new Products("Levis Jeans", "45", "iSetan", null));
    db.addProduct(new Products("Coffee Voucher 1", "20", "Starbucks", null));
    db.addProduct(new Products("Food voucher 1", "10", "Takashimaya", null));
    db.addProduct(new Products("Abcd", "25", "ntuc", "male"));

    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all products..");
    List<Products> productsList = db.getAllProducts();

    for(Products p: productsList)
    {
        String log = "ID: " + p.getID() +" ,Name: " + p.getProductName() + " ,Price: $" + p.getProductPrice() +
                " ,Vendor: " + p.getProductVendor() + " ,Gender: " + p.getProductGender();
        Log.d("Results: ", log);
    }
```

Below is my database file where I have added the CRUD functionalities. It's just a snippet to show relevant methods.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productsManager";
private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";

private static final String KEY_ID = "product_ID";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "product_name";
private static final String KEY_PRICE = "product_price";
private static final String KEY_VENDOR = "product_vendor";
private static final String KEY_GENDER = "product_for_gender";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +  KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + "TEXT,"
            + KEY_PRICE + "INTEGER," + KEY_VENDOR + "TEXT," + KEY_GENDER + "TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addProduct (Products products)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, products.getProductName());
    values.put(KEY_PRICE, products.getProductPrice());
    values.put(KEY_VENDOR, products.getProductVendor());
    values.put(KEY_GENDER, products.getProductGender());

    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public Products getProduct(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PRICE, KEY_VENDOR, KEY_GENDER},
            KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Products products = new Products(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1),
            cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));

    return products;
}

public List<Products> getAllProducts()
{
    List<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<Products>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
             Products products = new Products();
             products.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
             products.setProductName(cursor.getString(1));
             products.setProductPrice(cursor.getString(2));
             products.setProductVendor(cursor.getString(3));
             products.setProductGender(cursor.getString(4));
             productsList.add(products);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return productsList;
}
```

I'm not sure if the database has been opened or if the Logcat is not capturing the data when I open the virtual device. I open the logcat, run the AVD and open my app and filter the processes but it only shows choreography and a couple of other things. The log file is written in my first Main class, so I assume that when the app opens and the page is rendered, it should read the logs and write it into the logcat.

Comment: Do you see your device in the upper-left drop down menu of the Android monitor? Is your Log level in android monitor set to Verbose or Debug? Have you tried setting your filters to "No filters"?

Comment: This is what I see: https://gyazo.com/c9e796973c3b648e079fc93601651bac